# Croatia - Pula/Porec taxi prices

Tags: taxis, croatia

I am planning to have my vacation in Istria this year, and I was thinking Porec city. As I found some nice accommodation somewhere close to the city (about 5 Km) but I would rather use taxis to travel within the city.

Would anyone know what's the price per km inside these cities if I were to use a taxi?

Comment: I went to Pula last year and I don't really know about taxis. They are not driving around like in other mayor cities in the world. Perhaps you could mail a [taxi service](http://www.taxipula.com/pricelist.html) which you can find on google and ask if they also offer short rides and what the price will be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's any fixed cost per KM. Usually, taxi companies operate over various slab/bracket rates. For example, if the distance would be less than 10KM, the cost might be $X/KM & for distance between 10-25KM, the rate would be $XX/KM.
If you know the pickup & drop locations in Croatia, you can check the approximate rates over https://www.eurotaxi.mobi/

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The Pula Tourist Information has an online summary of the price list from [Taxi Pula](http://pulainfo.hr/en/prijevoz/taxi-pula/62/).

The pickup fee is 15 Kuna and they charge 10 Kuna per kilometer. Without any additional charges, e.g. for waiting or luggage, you would pay 65 Kuna for a 5 km trip.

For trips longer than 20 km, the fare is negotiable. I also read somewhere that during the summer months, there is a permanent shortage of taxis in the Pula area and all trips are subject to negotiable prices, where the real charge may easily end up three or four times higher than the official price list.